# google companion ad not playing on iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, ads, google-ima

we have video which we've connected to Google's Interactive Media Ads. It's all working splendid, until we figured out it isn't working on iOS iPhone devices. Funny thing is that it's not going to play even on macOS Google Chrome if we toggle device toolbar and set Dimensions: iPhone (any).

This is the log in console after we try to play video (and request ad on click):

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
    at VB.k.md (ima3.js:513:1543)

Uncaught Error: addEventListener and attachEvent are unavailable.

Uncaught TypeError: this.h.load is not a function
```

and after a while, we receive:

```
errorCode: 402
errorMessage: "VAST media file loading reached a timeout of 8 seconds."
type: "adPlayError"
```

I've investigated this whole day, and tried to add props such as 'playsinline', 'muted', autoplay={false}, window.google.ima.settings.setDisableCustomPlaybackForIOS10Plus(true), but nothing seems to work.